# How to find error when app has stopped at runtime?

Tags: android, sqlite, backup, logcat

I have an Android app that has a feature to export the SQLiteDatabase into a file in the External Storage. It runs okay on my phone (Redmi 4X) but in other phones (like Samsung SM-J105b), it crashes when I do a backup.

Here's my code for the backup:

```
private void backupDB() throws IOException {

    String backupDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FDRMobile/Backups/";
    File backupDir = new File( backupDirectory, "");
    if (!backupDir.exists()) {
        backupDir.mkdirs();
    }
    final String inFileName = "/data/data/com.scbpfsdgis.fdrmobile/databases/FEMobile.db";

    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd_HHMMSS", Locale.getDefault());

    String bakFile = "BAK_" + df.format(date) + ".db";
    this.backupFileName = bakFile;
    backupDirectory += bakFile;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(backupDirectory);

    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

I don't know how to write a logcat text file.

Comment: Why do you want to write logcat to file? And do you mean you want to receive the log being sent to your email if any device crash?

Comment: A crash reporting service would be an easier way to go ,  Firebase crashlytics  is a great pleace to start

Comment: @Tam Huynh - i want to know why the app crashes so maybe an error log is possible.

Comment: If i can have the stack trace in a text file, it would be better. Do you know where in this code the app could possibly have crashed?

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed has suggested you with `Firebase Crashlytics`, I currently use that tool too from its former `Fabric.io Crashlytics`. It pushes the stack trace, device info, your custom info along with the crash almost instantly to your dashboard and email. You should try that too https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: Like @FarabiAbdelwahed said - you could use crashlytics. A few lines of code and you get error reporting for all your crashes

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will take a note of them.

Answer (score 0):

Android application stores logs of running application in a file. You can retrieve the log using following steps:

1. Install the Android Debug Bridge using http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html
2. Instructions on installing Android Debug Bridge are located here:
   http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android- debug-bridge-utility
3. Run the following commands:
   “adb logcat -c" (This clears the logs.)
4. Reproduce the issue.
5. Then, run the following command to capture the logs in a file:
   “adb logcat -d > Name_of_Log_File.txt"